# On Macbook, how to restore an older Time Machine backup using Migration Assistant?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, migration-assistant

I have a 2019 Macbook Pro with the latest Ventura version. I have daily Time Machine backups at 10:00pm ET.

Using Migration Assistant, how can I choose which Time Machine backup to restore, like I was able to with the old Time Machine app (where the `Restore` button is now greyed out). For example, I want to restore the backup from 2 days ago? I didn't see this option when I used Migration Assistant earlier today.

Note: Using MacOS Recovery (restart -> <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> -> MacOS Recovery), it just tells you to use Migration Assistant.